# T-SQL: List all Variables in Scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to print all variables in scope of a SP execution after an exception so that I would have more insights of what went wrong during the failure. How can you do that?

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @Var1 AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'variable 1'
    DECLARE @Var2 AS INT = 5
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  @ErMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR(@ErMessage, @ErSeverity, @ErState);

    -- Print all @variable values like "@Var1: variable 1, ..."

    RETURN -1
END CATCH
```

Comment: Add your variable's values to the @ErMessage before raising the error, then make sure to log all poped errors. Your variables must be declared outside of the try for this.

Comment: There is no metadata function, view or other thingamajig that gives you any information on variables. You have to keep track of all of them yourself and write them out (you can use `CONCAT` to make this less tedious, as it performs conversions on the fly). This shouldn't be too hard since scoping for variables in T-SQL is fairly obvious. (And @EzLo's remark is wrong: variables are batch scoped, not lexically scoped, so `@Var1` is available inside the `CATCH` regardless of where it's declared.)